# How to create Breakout Game in Java

Tags: java

This question have been asked before. I have seen the answers but not quite works for me. I am creating a Breakout game. I have already created the ball, the paddle and the bricks. I have implemented how to make the ball bounce of the walls and first row of bricks.

I cannot figure out how to make the bricks disappear after they are hit by the ball. I am trying to store the bricks in an array, so I could just remove it from the array, when it is hit by the ball. Help is much appreciated.

Here is the code I have so far.

```
     import java.awt.*;
        import java.awt.event.*;
        import javax.swing.*;
        import javax.swing.event.MouseInputAdapter;
        import java.io.*;
        import sun.audio.*; //Used to play sounds

        public class Breakout {
            //Creating all the things we will need
            public static JPanel display = new DisplayPanel();
            public static JPanel controls = new JPanel();
            public static JLabel scoreNum;
            public static JLabel livesNum;
            public static int xPos = 250, score = 0, lives = 3;
            public static Boolean grabbed = false;
            public static int cx, cy;
            public static int bx, by, angle;
            public static int[] bricks  = new int[10];


            public static Timer time = new Timer(20,new Ticker());

            public static void main(String[] args)
            {
                Breakout bo = new Breakout();

            }

            public Breakout()
            {        
                //This part should be quite familiar by now
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setSize(new Dimension(650,550));
                frame.setForeground(Color.black);
                frame.setTitle("Breakout");

                //Display panel data
                display.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,550));
                display.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

                //Bricks

                //Control components
                JLabel title = new JLabel("BREAKOUT");
                title.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                JLabel scoreLbl = new JLabel("  Score: ");
                scoreNum = new JLabel("  "+score);
                JLabel livesLbl = new JLabel("  Lives: ");
                livesNum = new JLabel("  "+lives);

                //Control panel data
                controls.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(133,550)); //Not exact, to account for bordering
                controls.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                controls.setLayout(new GridLayout(25,1)); //The no. of rows can control the button height
                controls.add(title);
                controls.add(scoreLbl);
                controls.add(scoreNum);
                controls.add(livesLbl);
                controls.add(livesNum);

                display.addMouseListener(new MouseSensor());
                display.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseSensor());

                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(controls,BorderLayout.WEST);
                frame.add(display,BorderLayout.EAST);

                frame.setVisible(true);

                initBall();
                beep();
                time.start();


            }

            public static void initBall()
            {
                bx = 150 + (int)(Math.random() * (100));
                by = 50 + (int)(Math.random() * (200));
                angle = (int)(Math.random() * (2));
            }

            public static void beep()
            {
                //This program requires a sound file in the directory
                //that you use for external files.
                //You can use ANY sound that you give the name below,
                //but the one I use is found here:
                //http://www.soundjay.com/button/beep-2.wav
                try { 
                    AudioPlayer p = AudioPlayer.player;
                    AudioStream snd = new AudioStream(new FileInputStream("beep-2a.wav"));
                    p.start(snd); //This sequence is used to play sounds in JAVA
                }
                catch(IOException e) {}
            }

            public static class DisplayPanel extends JPanel
            {
                public void paintComponent (Graphics g)
                {   

                    int num_rows =  2;
                    int num_cols = 5;
                    int y_offset = 10;
                    int x_offset = 20;
                    int brick_height = 30;
                    int brick_width = 75;
                    int brick_sep = 20;

                    super.paintComponent(g);


                    g.setColor(Color.green);
                    for (int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++){
                    int y = y_offset + (i * (brick_height + brick_sep));

                    for (int j = 0; j < num_cols; j++){
                    int x = (x_offset) + (j * (brick_width + brick_sep));
                    g.fillRect (x, y, brick_width, brick_height );
                    }
                }
                    if (grabbed)
                        g.setColor(Color.blue); //Highlight if active
                    else
                        g.setColor(Color.black);
                    g.fillRect(xPos-30,480,60,15); //Draw paddle at current location

                    if(lives > 0)
                        g.setColor(Color.red);
                    else
                        g.setColor(Color.white); //Ball is "invisible" if game over
                    g.fillOval(bx,by,14,14);
                }
            }



            public static class MouseSensor extends MouseInputAdapter {
                public MouseSensor() {}

                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
                {
                    cx = e.getX();
                    cy = e.getY();

                    if ((cy > 470)&&(cy < 490)&&(cx > xPos-30)&&(cx < xPos+30))
                        grabbed = true; //If you click on the paddle, grab it!
                    display.repaint();
                }

                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
                {
                    grabbed = false;
                    display.repaint();
                }

                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e)
                {
                    cx = e.getX();
                    if (grabbed)
                    {
                        if (cx < 30)
                            cx = 30;
                        if (cx > 470)
                            cx = 470;
                        xPos = cx;
                    }
                    display.repaint(); //Move the grabbed paddle with the mouse
                }
            }

            public static class Ticker implements ActionListener
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
                {
                    //Angle 0: upper right, Angle 1: upper left
                    //Angle 2: lower right, Angle 3: lower left
                    int d = 5; //Displacement: No. of pixels to move per tick of timer
                    if(angle == 0)
                    { bx+=d; by-=d; } //Add to x, reduce y; moves upper right
                    else if (angle == 1)
                    { bx-=d; by-=d; } //Reduce x, reduce y; moves upper left
                    else if (angle == 2)
                    { bx+=d; by+=d; } //You get the idea
                    else if (angle == 3)
                    { bx-=d; by+=d; } //Ditto

                    //Collision Detection
                    if (bx > 482) //Hitting the right wall
                    {
                        if (angle == 0) //If going upper-right...
                            angle = 1; //go upper-left after bouncing
                        else if (angle == 2) //If going lower-right...
                            angle = 3; //go lower-left after hitting right wall
                    }
                    else if (bx < 3) //Hitting left wall
                    {
                        if (angle == 1)
                            angle = 0;
                        else if (angle == 3)
                            angle = 2;
                    }
                    else if (by < 3) //Hitting top
                    {
                        if (angle == 0)
                            angle = 2;
                        else if (angle == 1)
                            angle = 3;
                    }
                    //Note; no detection at bottom, since that's how you lose
                    else if ((by > 460)&&(by < 480)) //Deflection height of paddle
                    {
                        if ((bx > (xPos-30))&&(bx < (xPos+30))) //Deflected by paddle
                        {
                            Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep(); //Play sound
                            if (angle == 2)
                                angle = 0;
                            else if (angle == 3)
                                angle = 1;
                            score+= 10;//Modify this for your assignment (see notes)
                            scoreNum.setText("  "+score);
                        }
                    }
                    else if ((by < 90)&& (bx > 20) && (bx < 95))//Block 1
                    {
                        if (angle == 0)
                            angle = 2;
                        else if (angle == 1)
                            angle = 3;

                    }

                    else if ((by < 90)&& (bx > 115) && (bx < 190))//Block 2
                    {
                        if (angle == 0)
                            angle = 2;
                        else if (angle == 1)
                            angle = 3;
                    }

                    else if ((by < 90)&& (bx > 210) && (bx < 285))//Block 3
                    {
                        if (angle == 0)
                            angle = 2;
                        else if (angle == 1)
                            angle = 3;
                    }

                    else if ((by < 90)&& (bx > 305) && (bx < 380))//Block 4
                    {
                        if (angle == 0)
                            angle = 2;
                        else if (angle == 1)
                            angle = 3;
                    }

                    else if ((by < 90)&& (bx > 400) && (bx < 475))//Block 5
                    {
                        if (angle == 0)
                            angle = 2;
                        else if (angle == 1)
                            angle = 3;
                    }

                    else if (by > 530) //Missed; ball goes too low in y-value
                    {
                        lives--;
                        if (lives > 0)
                        {
                            livesNum.setText("  "+lives);
                            initBall();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            time.stop();
                            livesNum.setText("  GAME OVER");
                        }
                    }
                    display.repaint();
                }
            }
        }
```

here is the code where I created the bricks

```
    g.setColor(Color.green);
            for (int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++){
            int y = y_offset + (i * (brick_height + brick_sep));

            for (int j = 0; j < num_cols; j++){
            int x = (x_offset) + (j * (brick_width + brick_sep));
            g.fillRect (x, y, brick_width, brick_height );
            }
```

What I want to do is disappear when i ball hits them, and for the ball to bounce off as well.

Here is the code from which the ball bounces of:

```
else if ((by < 90)&& (bx > 20) && (bx < 95))//Block 1
            {
                if (angle == 0)
                    angle = 2;
                else if (angle == 1)
                    angle = 3;

            }

            else if ((by < 90)&& (bx > 115) && (bx < 190))//Block 2
            {
                if (angle == 0)
                    angle = 2;
                else if (angle == 1)
                    angle = 3;
            }

            else if ((by < 90)&& (bx > 210) && (bx < 285))//Block 3
            {
                if (angle == 0)
                    angle = 2;
                else if (angle == 1)
                    angle = 3;
            }

            else if ((by < 90)&& (bx > 305) && (bx < 380))//Block 4
            {
                if (angle == 0)
                    angle = 2;
                else if (angle == 1)
                    angle = 3;
            }

            else if ((by < 90)&& (bx > 400) && (bx < 475))//Block 5
            {
                if (angle == 0)
                    angle = 2;
                else if (angle == 1)
                    angle = 3;
            }
```

I don't know how to make them disappear as they are hit by the ball.

Comment: You shouldn't really expect help if you just dump some code here without isolating the problem. What are you doing to make bricks disappear now? What are other approaches you've seen and tried, and why don't you think they work?

Comment: g.setColor(Color.green);
            for (int i = 0; i < num_rows; i++){
            int y = y_offset + (i * (brick_height + brick_sep));

            for (int j = 0; j < num_cols; j++){
            int x = (x_offset) + (j * (brick_width + brick_sep));
            g.fillRect (x, y, brick_width, brick_height );
            }

Comment: Unless there is a problem you should try to work it out on your own, and then ask for help if you run into any issues... Your code above doesn't present a "problem" but more of a "do it for me"

Comment: Hasn't anyone told you that you should use `enum`s instead of magic numbers like `angle == 0` or `angle == 3`?

Comment: Thanks @EpicPandaForce The bouncing is not the problem, that is fine. I cannot figure out how to make the blocks disappear.

Comment: oh that's simple, you are just drawing them out at specific locations, rather than keep track of objects, intersecting them with your ball, then actually removing them from the grid.

Comment: Hmm I see, so instead of drawing them i need to create objects and track the collisions. Do you happen to give me a little guide in how to about doing that? @EpicPandaForce

Comment: you have a "bricks" array, but you are not using it - you should be using it :p